# Синхронизация действий на странице Java Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

Всем доброго дня!

У меня есть задание: есть сайт, на нем есть список комнат. Пользователь может войти в одну из них. И теперь главная проблема в том, что в комнате ты можешь делать любое действие. Не важно, к примеру, нажимать на кнопку и рандомно генерировать цифру и выводить ее на сайт.

**Вопрос** как сделать так чтобы изменение на странице увидели все пользователи?

Если кто знает помогите пожалуйста или хотя бы скажите как это называется.

Comment: Если необходимо чтобы все пользователи в режиме реального времени видели действия друг друга, то это называется websocket'ы.

Comment: То что упомянул оратор выше или же push-notification